# Does git revert also use the 3-way-merge?

Tags: git, merge, revert, git-revert, 3-way-merge

When I run `git revert`, it can happen, that a conflict occurs. Does git rely on the 3-way-merge, as it is depicted in the question [merge internals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30409863/git-merge-internals) (cf. table below) also for `revert`?

[image]

What is the merge base for a revert? In [What are the three files in a 3-way merge for interactive rebasing using git and meld?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36993683/what-are-the-three-files-in-a-3-way-merge-for-interactive-rebasing-using-git-and) it is quite clear, but its hard to imagine this for a revert.

```
A - B - C - D - C^-1
```

(If I want to revert `C` at the end.)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a base.  (Side note: this code has changed a lot since I looked at it years ago.  I picked up some of this for my recent cherry-pick answer, which you have linked here.)

Both `git cherry-pick` and `git revert` are implemented by the same source files (`builtin/revert.c` and `sequencer.c`).

As you say, the tricky part is deciding what to fake up for the merge base.  In your example, we're undoing the `B`-to-`C` diffs.  Here's the actual source code (in `sequencer.c`), stripped down somewhat:

```
if (opts->action == REPLAY_REVERT) {
        base = commit;
        base_label = msg.label;
        next = parent;
        next_label = msg.parent_label;
        strbuf_addstr(&msgbuf, "Revert \"");
        strbuf_addstr(&msgbuf, msg.subject);
        strbuf_addstr(&msgbuf, "\"\n\nThis reverts commit ");
        strbuf_addstr(&msgbuf, oid_to_hex(&commit->object.oid));

        if (commit->parents && commit->parents->next) {
                strbuf_addstr(&msgbuf, ", reversing\nchanges made to ");
                strbuf_addstr(&msgbuf, oid_to_hex(&parent->object.oid));
        }
        strbuf_addstr(&msgbuf, ".\n");
} else {
```

[this is the cherry-pick case, included just for completeness]

```
        const char *p;

        base = parent;
        base_label = msg.parent_label;
        next = commit;
        next_label = msg.label;
```

When we enter here, `commit` points to data for `C` and `parent` points to data for `B`.  The assignment to variable `base` is what sets the merge base, and `next`-vs-`base` is what to bring in.  For cherry-pick, the commit's parent (possibly chosen via `-m`) is the merge base.  For revert, the commit itself is the merge base and the parent (again possibly from `-m`) is what-to-bring-in.

The other way to get the same effect (which is how this was done many years ago, and until recently, I thought this was still being used) is to reverse-apply a commit as produced by `git format-patch`.  In this case, the constructed base version is the second hash (the `B` part from the `A..B` part of a textual diff):

```
/*
 * This represents a "patch" to a file, both metainfo changes
 * such as creation/deletion, filemode and content changes represented
 * as a series of fragments.
 */
struct patch {
[snip]
    char old_sha1_prefix[41];
    char new_sha1_prefix[41];

static void reverse_patches(struct patch *p)
{
[snip]
            swap(p->old_sha1_prefix, p->new_sha1_prefix);
```

The `reverse_patches` function is called after extracting the text into a series of patches, i.e., after the code that extracts the hashes from the `index` lines, putting the `A` and `B` parts into the old and new prefix fields.  Then (after `reverse_patches`), when actually applying each patch, git uses the saved old and new sha1 values to fake a 3-way merge (if `git am` is given `--3way`).  So by reverse-applying a text patch, we would get the new file as the base and the original as the target, just as with the `sequencer.c` code.