# How does git compare two files while merging?

Tags: git, git-merge

How does git compare two files. Which algorithms are used to compare two files? Does it compare line by line while merging?

I can't be sure whether comparison of two files produce a conflict or not while merging.

Comment: What do you mean by "produce conflict"? Comparing two files with Git cannot do any harm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git merge internals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30409863/git-merge-internals)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-merge%5D+how+does+merge+work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44724154/7976758

Comment: this is not something you need to know: if there is a merge conflict, git will tell you that there is a merge conflict, and `git status` will show you where. If you use the command line - if you use any IDE or sensible code editor with git integration, things typically get even nicer. Protip: read a tutorial on how to use git and learn the tool a bit. It's used by everyone, sure, but it's still a tool you should read up on [before asking questions based on assumptions that could have been avoided](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several merge strategies. 3-way merge algorithm recurse is used by default in Git.

3-way algorithm uses last common commit.

For example:

```
master: A -> B -> C
```

Create new branch

```
master: A -> B -> C
                   \
branch:             D
```

Some new commits

```
master: A -> B -> C -> E
                   \
branch:             D -> F
```

Assume all changes made in a.txt (empty cell corresponds to empty line)

```
 commit C         commit E         commit F 
----------       ----------       ----------
  line a                            line a
  line b         new line d
  line c                          new line e
                   line a           line b
                   line b         new line f
                   line c           
                 new line g         line c
```

What happens if we merge two branch (commit E, commit F). Does it produce a merge conflict?. Answer is no. Because git does not compare a file line by line. It compares context of the lines.

Align the a.txt file

```
 commit C         commit E         commit F 
----------       ----------       ----------

                 new line d

  line a-----------line a-----------line a

                                  new line e
  line b-----------line b-----------line b
                                  new line f

  line c-----------line c-----------line c
                 new line g
```

In the above table, changes are aligned. lines in the commit C (ancestor commit) are our references. git compares the neighbor of the reference lines. In the example, we have 4 slot:

- above the line a : commit e adds new line d
- below the line a : commit f adds new line e
- below the line b : commit e adds new line f
- below the line c : commit g adds new line g

As you see, only one of the branches (commit E, commit F) may add something new or both of them may add same thing. Otherwise, A merge conflict is occurred.

Answer (score 20):

The key to understanding `git merge` is that Git doesn't compare *two* things.  Git compares *three* things.

Git can't compare all three directly.  It has to compare them two at a time.  Two of the things are the two branch tip versions of the files (or branch tip commits; I'll talk more about this in a moment), but Git doesn't compare those *to each other*.  This is where the third one comes in: the third file is the *merge base* version of the file.

Remember that the goal of a merge is to *combine changes*.  But Git doesn't store changes.  Git stores *snapshots*.  Every commit stores every file whole and intact: given one commit, Git gets the whole `README.md`, the whole `main.py`, whatever other files are in this particular commit, that's the version in the commit.

To get changes from snapshots, we need *two* snapshots: the old one, and the new one.  Then we play a game of [Spot the Difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_the_difference).  For Git, that's `git diff`: you give it the hash ID of the old commit, and the hash ID of the new commit, and it makes a diff for each file that's changed between the two.  The output of `git diff` is a series of instructions: *delete these lines, add these other lines*.  If you take the original snapshot and apply the instructions, you get the new snapshot.

When we're *merging*, though, we want to take the work done by (say) Alice, and *combine* it with the work done by Bob.  So what Git does is:

- Find the best *shared* commit, that both Alice and Bob started with.
- Compare the *shared* commit's files to Alice's files.  This is *what Alice changed*.
- Compare the *shared* commit's files to Bob's files.  This is *what Bob changed.*

We call the shared commit—the one that both Alice and Bob started with—the *merge base*.  That's the third input to a merge.  Git finds this merge base commit automatically, using the history—the commits—in your repository.  This means that you need to have both Alice's *and* Bob's commits, and all the commits that lead up to those two branch tips, so that you also have the common starting point commit.

Remember that each commit, along with its snapshot, records some information *about* the snapshot: the name and email address of the person who made it, for instance.  There's a date-and-time-stamp for *when* they made it, and a log message that they can use to explain *why* they made it.  It also stores the raw hash ID of its immediate *parent* commit: the commit they used, via `git checkout`, to start from before they made *their* commit.  These parent hash IDs form a backwards-looking chain: if both Alice and Bob started from commit `H`, and Alice made two commits `I` and `J` and Bob made two commits `K` and `L`, the backwards chains look like this:

```
                I <-J   <-- (Alice's latest)
               /
... <-F <-G <-H
               \
                K <-L   <-- (Bob's latest)
```

Git will automatically find `H`, which is where Alice and Bob both started from.<sup>1</sup>

Having found `H`, Git now, in effect, runs these two `git diff` commands:

- `git diff --find-renames hash-of-H hash-of-J`: what Alice changed
- `git diff --find-renames hash-of-H hash-of-L`: what Bob changed

The merge process now combines these changes.  For each file in `H`:

- Did Alice change the file?  Did Bob change the file?
- If neither changed the file, use any copy of the file: all three are the same.
- If Alice changed the file and Bob didn't, use Alice's version.
- If Bob changed the file and Alice didn't, use Bob's version.
- If both changed the file, *combine* their changes.  This is where a merge conflict *could* occur.

> Does [Git] compare line by line while merging?

The answer to this is both no and yes.  As you can now see, there's no comparison of Alice's version to Bob's version.  There *is* a comparison—sort of line-by-line; it's whatever `git diff` does for comparing—of the *base* version, to Alice's, and there is an identical comparison of the *base* version to Bob's.  The whole process kicks off by doing a full commit-wide comparison of the two pairs of *commits*.  Within that commit-wide comparison, having found that both Alice and Bob changed *some particular file(s)*, **now** the line-by-line, or really diff-hunk-by-diff-hunk, comparisons matter.  But they're from a *third* version.

> I don't want to check each time manually using "git diff".

You don't have to.  You can if you *want* to, but to do that, you need to find the merge-base commit, using `git merge-base` perhaps.  But if you don't want to, then ... don't.  *Git* will find the merge-base commit; *Git* will do the two separate `git diff` operations; *Git* will combine Alice's changes with Bob's changes, and declare a conflict if the changed lines overlap—or in some cases, [abut](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/abut), or if both span to the end of file.

(For Git, if both Alice and Bob made *exactly* the same changes to *exactly* the same lines, Git just takes one copy of the change.  Other VCSes may declare a conflict here, either out of laziness—they don't check that the changes were the same, just that they overlapped—or paranoia: if both changed the same lines, maybe the correct result is *not* just to use one copy of the change.  Git just says "the correct result is one copy of the change".)

In any case, Git applies the *combined* changes to the *merge base* version of the file.  That's the result, possibly with a merge conflict (and merge conflict markers inside the work-tree copy of the file).

Finally, note the `--find-renames` in the two `git diff` commands.  Git will try to tell whether Alice and/or Bob *renamed* any of the files in the merge-base commit.  If so, Git will try to keep the renaming in the final result.  This is true regardless of whether it was Alice or Bob that did the renaming.  If both Alice *and* Bob renamed the file, Git doesn't know which final name to use, and declares a *rename/rename* conflict.  There are similar issues if Alice or Bob *deletes* the file while the other one modifies it, and there's one last conflict that occurs if both Alice and Bob add a *new* file with the same name.  These kinds of conflicts are what I call *high level* conflicts: they affect whole files (and/or their names) rather than individual lines *within* a file.  This difference between a low-level conflict (lines within a file) and a high-level one matters if and when you use the `-Xours` or `-Xtheirs` option.

---

<sup>1</sup>This works even if Alice only made *one* commit, say `J`, atop (say) Carol's one commit `I` that Carol made atop `H`.  The common *starting point* is still `H`.  Git doesn't even look at the authorship of each commit: it just works backwards from the two branch tips.

Comment: thanks !! This is the most beautiful & fundamental explanation I found so far.

Answer (score -1):

It uses [delta compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding#Git). We have to understand that when we `add` a file in get, we create an object that has its sha sum calculated and recorded in the index. What git does is that, through `git-repack`, it takes compressed objects (compressed using delta compression) into a pack (a file). When you are making commits, git is taking the objects that are not compressed and using some internal rules, it is creating a file that contains the differences and the similarities between the objects. This creation of a pack uses delta compression.

This delta compression, which is just delta differencing, is the thing you are asking about. I guess the scope of how this algorithm works is beyond this question, so here are a few references to get you going.

[Algorithms for Delta Compression](http://engineering.nyu.edu/~suel/papers/delta.pdf)

[How git treats each file](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-What-is-Git%3F)

[git-repack](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack)

[delta differencing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_differencing)

Comment: The question is about diffs for merging, not diffs for packing.

Comment: @RaymondChen no. The question is about algorithms that are used to produce diffs. I just gave additional information to that topic. My answer DID cover the question at hand.

Comment: Delta compression is an algorithm to differentiate binary files. I don't know if `git` uses it to *store* blobs but it certainly doesn't use it for diff and merge.

Comment: fair enough and point taken. if I took the time to search better I would have found these two sources - [artitle](https://fabiensanglard.net/git_code_review/diff.php) and [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)