# Git detects files as newer after reverting a merge, so it doesn't show conflict

Tags: git, github, version-control, branch, git-flow

I have this scenario:
There are 2 branches, '**develop**' and '**feature-branch**'. This two branches have been growing over time each one independently. Now, 16 of November of last year, a merge was done from '**feature-branch**' to '**develop**'.
This merge should not have been done so it was reverted on 19 of November.
The problem: now the files in develop are newer, so when doing a merge from 'develop' to the branch to integrate both, git keeps the files in **develop**.
This is a problem because there is code on the branch which is necessary, and since it doesn't create conflicts, I'm not able to integrate them. I would need to manually check every file and check the logic, which is not ideal.
Is there any way of fixing this?

Comment: Merging is not about which files are *newer*. Merging, in Git, is about *combining work*. This requires figuring out what "work" was done, which in turn requires locating the *merge base* commit, then running two `git diff` commands. See, for instance, [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56894290/1256452).

Comment: In general, if some merge was done, then reverted, and now needs to be re-performed, the usual approach is to revert the reversion. In some cases this is not suitable though; in those cases, it makes sense to copy some (but not all) of the commits whose *work* was reverted to new-and-improved commits in one of the two commit-streams that will be merged, or to the result of merging those two commits-streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Checkout a new local branch called '**prepare-develop-for-merge-into-feature-branch**' based on the **merge-revert commit** of '**develop'**.
   `git checkout -b prepare-develop-for-merge-into-feature-branch <commit-id-of-merge-revert>`
2. Create a commit that reverts the merge-revert
   `git revert HEAD`
3. Checkout '**feature-branch**'
   `git checkout feature-branch`
4. Merge '**prepare-develop-for-merge-into-feature-branch**' into
   it
   `git merge prepare-develop-for-merge-into-feature-branch`
5. Merge actual '**develop**' into '**feature-branch**'
   `git merge develop`

The result should then look like what you'd expect it to look if that merge-revert never happened.

---

Note: There are other approaches to solving this (e.g. reverting the merge-revert direclty on top of feature-branch). However, I've chosen this approach, because it should cause `git blame` to still point at the original commits (instead of the revert-revert) while also keeping possible merge-conflicts to a minimum.